# Flume 1.2.0 custom Source

Tags: java, hadoop, flume

I have a homegrown event collection and processing framework which i am looking to potentially replace with Apache Flume 1.2.0 as we are going to start loading data into Hadoop.  Since Flume has no HTTP Source, i am writing a custom source with an embedded Tomcat server. I am following the documentation at http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#custom-source however when i start i get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No known runner type for source
>   com.xxx.xxx.flume.TestSource@5219f360     at
>   org.apache.flume.SourceRunner.forSource(SourceRunner.java:54)     at
>   org.apache.flume.conf.properties.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.loadSources(PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:340)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.conf.properties.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.load(PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.conf.file.AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.doLoad(AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.conf.file.AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.access$300(AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.conf.file.AbstractFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.java:202)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i figured it out.  The documentation on the Flume website does not mention a custom implementation should implement not the Source interface but either the EventDrivenSource or PollableSource interface.